# How to sum by levels in Hierarchical (tree)? in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, tree, oracle-sqldeveloper, hierarchical-data

I am stuck on how to sum by levels, I have the following query:

```js
SELECT 
TREE.*, 
FVVVL.DESCRIPTION,
--SUM(VALUES_GL.TOTAL)
VALUES_GL.TOTAL
FROM (
    SELECT 
    PK1_START_VALUE, 
    PARENT_PK1_VALUE, 
    CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE "Cycle",
    LEVEL, 
    SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(PK1_START_VALUE, '/') "Path" 
    FROM 
    FND_TREE_NODE 
    WHERE TREE_CODE = 'CGM_ESF'
    START WITH PK1_START_VALUE = 'ESF_A'
    CONNECT BY NOCYCLE  PRIOR  PK1_START_VALUE = PARENT_PK1_VALUE AND LEVEL <= 5
    --ORDER SIBLINGS BY PK1_START_VALUE
) TREE
INNER JOIN FND_VS_VALUES_VL FVVVL ON FVVVL.VALUE = TREE.PK1_START_VALUE
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
    NVL(GLL.ACCOUNTED_DR, GLL.ACCOUNTED_CR * -1 ) AS TOTAL, 
    GLL.PERIOD_NAME, TO_CHAR(GLL.EFFECTIVE_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 
    GLL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID,
    GLL.LEDGER_ID,
    GCC.SEGMENT2
    FROM GL_JE_LINES GLL
    INNER JOIN GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GCC ON GLL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GLL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
) VALUES_GL ON VALUES_GL.SEGMENT2 = TREE.PK1_START_VALUE --AND TREE.LEVEL = 5
ORDER BY "Path"
```

[image: Expected result]

Explanation of what I did in excel:
Note: At the moment there are only 5 levels then that increases, but it would be like this:

- Level 4 should show the total of the sum of level 5.
- Level 3 should show the total of the sum of level 4.
- Level 2 must show the total of the sum of level 3
- Level 1 should show the total of the sum of level 2.

At the moment I have empty values:

[image: Problem]

Oracle FND_TREE_NODE table documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/applications-common/21d/oedma/fndtreenode-22816.html

Thank you.

Comment: I see you have put constraints in the SQL, but can you be sure you will always have 5 levels, not more or less in the real data? IIRC: The Kimball Ross book called The Data Warehouse Toolkit had a solution for this.

Comment: At the moment there are 5 levels, but I do not know very well how Oracle Cloud Fusion saves it because they are tables of them so I put the documentation, but if I put that START WITH PK1_START_VALUE = 'ESF_A' and also if I do not put LEVEL <= 5 tells me that it enters a loop.

Comment: It seems that you are asking for spreaadshhet-like calculations. Did you try to use modeling of your data (MODEL clause). Think it could solve your problem. More at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/sqlmodel.htm (old one but ok).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MODEL clause example on simulated dataset derived from upper picture. It looks ok. Maybe you can try to adjust it to your data.

```
WITH
    dataset AS          -- dataset simulation
        (
          Select '13050501' "PK1", Null "PRNT", '0' "CCL", '1' "LVL", 100 "AMNT" From DUAL UNION ALL
          Select '13050501' "PK1", Null "PRNT", '0' "CCL", '1' "LVL", 110 "AMNT" From DUAL UNION ALL
          Select '13050501' "PK1", Null "PRNT", '0' "CCL", '1' "LVL", 120 "AMNT" From DUAL UNION ALL
          Select '13050501' "PK1", 'ESF_A' "PRNT", '0' "CCL", '2' "LVL", 200 "AMNT" From DUAL UNION ALL
          Select '13050501' "PK1", 'ESF_A' "PRNT", '0' "CCL", '2' "LVL", 210 "AMNT" From DUAL UNION ALL
          Select '13050501' "PK1", 'ESF_ACT' "PRNT", '0' "CCL", '3' "LVL", 300 "AMNT" From DUAL UNION ALL
          Select '13050501' "PK1", 'ESF_ACT' "PRNT", '0' "CCL", '3' "LVL", 310 "AMNT" From DUAL UNION ALL
          Select '13050501' "PK1", 'ESF_ACT' "PRNT", '0' "CCL", '3' "LVL", 320 "AMNT" From DUAL UNION ALL
          Select '13050501' "PK1", 'ESF_AC' "PRNT", '0' "CCL", '4' "LVL", 400 "AMNT" From DUAL UNION ALL
          Select '13050501' "PK1", 'ESF_AC' "PRNT", '0' "CCL", '4' "LVL", 410 "AMNT" From DUAL UNION ALL
          Select '13050501' "PK1", 'ESF_ADCC' "PRNT", '0' "CCL", '5' "LVL", 500 "AMNT" From DUAL UNION ALL
          Select '13050501' "PK1", 'ESF_ADCC' "PRNT", '0' "CCL", '5' "LVL", 510 "AMNT" From DUAL UNION ALL
          Select '13050501' "PK1", 'ESF_ADCC' "PRNT", '0' "CCL", '5' "LVL", 520 "AMNT" From DUAL
        ),
    level_sums AS
        (   
            SELECT  LVL "LVL", Sum(AMNT)  "TOTAL", Count(*) "RECS"
            FROM    dataset
            GROUP BY LVL
            ORDER BY LVL
        ),
    all_data AS
        (
            SELECT
                ds.LVL || '_' || Count(ds.LVL) OVER(PARTITION BY ds.LVL ORDER BY ds.LVL, ds.PK1, ds.PRNT ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) "ID",
                Count(ds.LVL) OVER(PARTITION BY ds.LVL ORDER BY ds.LVL, ds.PK1, ds.PRNT ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)  "RN",
                CAST('/FULL/PATH/FROM/DATASET' as VARCHAR2(50)) "PATH",
                ds.PK1,
                ds.PRNT,
                ds.CCL,
                ds.LVL,
                ds.AMNT,
                ls.TOTAL
            FROM
                dataset ds
            INNER JOIN
                level_sums ls ON(ls.LVL = ds.LVL)
            ORDER BY ds.LVL, ds.PK1, ds.PRNT
        )
SELECT 
    PK1 "PK1_START_VALUE",
    PRNT "PARENT_PK1_VALUE",
    CCL "CYCLE",
    LVL "LEVEL",
    REPLACE('/' || REPLACE(PATH, '//', ''), '//', '/') "PATH",
    CASE WHEN SubStr(ID, 1, 1) = '0' THEN TOTAL ELSE AMNT END "TOTAL",
    CASE WHEN SubStr(ID, 1, 1) = '0' THEN 'SUM of level ' || To_Char(LVL - 1) ELSE 'Amount from dataset' END "NOTE"
FROM 
    (   SELECT ID, LVL, PK1, PRNT, CCL, PATH, AMNT, TOTAL  FROM all_data    )       -- Modeling happens here
        MODEL
            DIMENSION BY      (ID)
            MEASURES          (LVL, PATH, PK1, PRNT, CCL, AMNT, TOTAL)
                RULES ITERATE(5)
                    (
                        PK1['0' || '_' || To_Char(ITERATION_NUMBER + 1)]    =   Nvl(PRNT[To_Char(ITERATION_NUMBER + 2) || '_' || '1'], PK1[To_Char(ITERATION_NUMBER + 1) || '_' || '1']),
                        PRNT['0' || '_' || To_Char(ITERATION_NUMBER + 1)]   =   PRNT[To_Char(ITERATION_NUMBER + 1) || '_' || '1'],
                        CCL['0' || '_' || To_Char(ITERATION_NUMBER + 1)]    =   CCL[To_Char(ITERATION_NUMBER + 1) || '_' || '1'],
                        LVL['0' || '_' || To_Char(ITERATION_NUMBER + 1)]    =   LVL[To_Char(ITERATION_NUMBER + 1) || '_' || '1'], 
                        PATH['0' || '_' || To_Char(ITERATION_NUMBER + 1)]   =   PRNT[To_Char(ITERATION_NUMBER + 0) || '_' || '1'] || '/' || 
                                                                                PRNT[To_Char(ITERATION_NUMBER + 1) || '_' || '1'] || '/' || 
                                                                                CASE To_Char(ITERATION_NUMBER + 2) 
                                                                                    WHEN '6' 
                                                                                    THEN PK1[To_Char(ITERATION_NUMBER + 1) || '_' || '1'] 
                                                                                ELSE PRNT[To_Char(ITERATION_NUMBER + 2) || '_' || '1']  
                                                                                END,
                        TOTAL['0' || '_' || To_Char(ITERATION_NUMBER + 1)] = TOTAL[To_Char(ITERATION_NUMBER) || '_' || '1']
                    )
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN SubStr(ID, 1, 1) = '0' THEN '99' || To_Char(LVL) ELSE To_Char(9990 - LVL) END
--  
--  R e s u l t
--
--  PK1_START_VALUE PARENT_PK1_VALUE CYCLE LEVEL PATH                                                     TOTAL NOTE                                                
--  --------------- ---------------- ----- ----- --------------------------------------------------- ---------- -----------------------------------------------------
--  ESF_A                            0     1     /ESF_A                                                         SUM of level 0                                        
--  ESF_ACT         ESF_A            0     2     /ESF_A/ESF_ACT                                             330 SUM of level 1                                        
--  ESF_AC          ESF_ACT          0     3     /ESF_A/ESF_ACT/ESF_AC                                      410 SUM of level 2                                        
--  ESF_ADCC        ESF_AC           0     4     /ESF_ACT/ESF_AC/ESF_ADCC                                   930 SUM of level 3                                        
--  13050501        ESF_ADCC         0     5     /ESF_AC/ESF_ADCC/13050501                                  810 SUM of level 4                                        
--  13050501        ESF_ADCC         0     5     /FULL/PATH/FROM/DATASET                                    520 Amount from dataset                                   
--  13050501        ESF_ADCC         0     5     /FULL/PATH/FROM/DATASET                                    510 Amount from dataset                                   
--  13050501        ESF_ADCC         0     5     /FULL/PATH/FROM/DATASET                                    500 Amount from dataset                                   
--  13050501        ESF_AC           0     4     /FULL/PATH/FROM/DATASET                                    400 Amount from dataset                                   
--  13050501        ESF_AC           0     4     /FULL/PATH/FROM/DATASET                                    410 Amount from dataset                                   
--  13050501        ESF_ACT          0     3     /FULL/PATH/FROM/DATASET                                    310 Amount from dataset                                   
--  13050501        ESF_ACT          0     3     /FULL/PATH/FROM/DATASET                                    300 Amount from dataset                                   
--  13050501        ESF_ACT          0     3     /FULL/PATH/FROM/DATASET                                    320 Amount from dataset                                   
--  13050501        ESF_A            0     2     /FULL/PATH/FROM/DATASET                                    210 Amount from dataset                                   
--  13050501        ESF_A            0     2     /FULL/PATH/FROM/DATASET                                    200 Amount from dataset                                   
--  13050501                         0     1     /FULL/PATH/FROM/DATASET                                    120 Amount from dataset                                   
--  13050501                         0     1     /FULL/PATH/FROM/DATASET                                    110 Amount from dataset                                   
--  13050501                         0     1     /FULL/PATH/FROM/DATASET                                    100 Amount from dataset
```