# How to get cumulative sum of values in each level of Oracle hierarchical query?

Tags: oracle, hierarchical

This question is in continuation to my previous question on [hierarchical query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76104429/how-to-fix-oracle-hierarchical-query-returning-duplicate-records), where Im looking for cumulative sum of values at each level of the hierarchy.

For a schema like the following:

```
drop table t1 purge;

create table t1(en varchar2(10),bug number, mgr varchar2(10));
insert into t1 values('z',901,'x');
insert into t1 values('z',902,'x');
insert into t1 values('z',903,'x');
insert into t1 values('a',101,'z');
insert into t1 values('a',102,'z');
insert into t1 values('a',103,'z');
insert into t1 values('a',104,'z');
insert into t1 values('b',201,'a');
insert into t1 values('b',202,'a');
insert into t1 values('b',203,'a');
insert into t1 values('c',301,'z');
insert into t1 values('c',302,'z');
insert into t1 values('c',303,'z');
insert into t1 values('d',301,'c');
insert into t1 values('d',302,'c');
commit;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a30cb/2).

The output I'm expecting is :

```
MGR  EN   EN_BUG_COUNT  CUMULATIVE_BUG_COUNT    LEVEL
x    null         null                    15        0
x    z               3                    12        1
z    a               4                     7        2
a    b               3                     3        3
z    c               3                     5        2
c    d               2                     2        4
```

I have spent lot of time and found following links, but the queries they had used is very hard to comprehend:

1. [Oracle hierarchical queries data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66486601/oracle-hierarchical-queries-data)
2. [How to sum by levels in Hierarchical (tree)? in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72470361/how-to-sum-by-levels-in-hierarchical-tree-in-oracle)
3. [Getting counts at each level of a hierarchical query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025926/getting-counts-at-each-level-of-a-hierarchical-query)

Comment: Your expected output does not make sense as going from `(z, c)` to `(c, d)` goes from level 2 to 4 (not 3). And if you work backwards for the cumulative totals then `(c, d) = 2`, `(z, c) = 3 + (c, d) = 5`, `(a, b) = 3`, `(z, a) = 4 + (a, b) = 7` ... so far so good ... but then `(x, z) = 3 + (z, a) + (z, c) = 15` (not 12).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group the bugs and then use a hierarchical query to find the levels and use a correlated hierarchical query to sum the values for descendants:

```sql
WITH grouped_bugs (en, en_bug_count, mgr) AS (
  SELECT en,
         COUNT(*),
         mgr
  FROM   t1
  GROUP BY
         en, mgr
)
SELECT mgr,
       en,
       en_bug_count,
       ( SELECT SUM(en_bug_count)
         FROM   grouped_bugs i
         START WITH i.en = g.en
         CONNECT BY PRIOR en = mgr ) AS cumulative_bug_count,
       LEVEL
FROM   grouped_bugs g
START WITH mgr = 'x'
CONNECT BY PRIOR en = mgr
ORDER SIBLINGS BY en;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| MGR | EN | EN_BUG_COUNT | CUMULATIVE_BUG_COUNT | LEVEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | z | 3 | 15 | 1 |
| z | a | 4 | 7 | 2 |
| a | b | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| z | c | 3 | 5 | 2 |
| c | d | 2 | 2 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xhgOC940)